# WPF Custom control problem: 'Shape' does not have a public property named 'Background'

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, custom-controls, code-sharing

I'm trying to create a custom control that can be shared by both Silverlight and WPF. For the sake of this I don't use Triggers in my Custom control's templates which are not supported by Silverlight - instead I use Storyboard animations which seem to be supported by both platforms.

First, I made a Custom control which works well for Silverlight. Then tried to use it in WPF and kept getting the following runtime error:  ***Property path is not valid. 'Shape' does not have a public property named 'Background'.***

The following XAML in my Custom control template is the cause:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Hovered">
    <Storyboard>
       <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0"
                Storyboard.TargetName="PBorder"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="White" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

**What is the valid XAML syntax for this part of code for WPF specifically?**
**And is it possible to make this XAML valid for both Silverlight and WPF?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Shape` does not have a `Background` but instead it has a `Fill`(Background) and a `Stroke`(Border).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. The above code doesn't work in wpf with `Shape.Fill` as it doesn't with `Shape.Background`

Comment: OK. I've ended up with `(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)`, it works.

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work`? Does it show any error in `Output Window`?

Comment: It gives the error: `"'Fill' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)'".`